# NSXmlParserError for Twitter

Tags: ios, twitter, oauth, nsxmlparser

I am trying to get Twitter feeds in my ios app, i have successfully authenticated the user and got the accessToken. I have used MGTwitterEngine for this. Now when i am trying to get the Feeds with the above method;

```
[_engine getUserTimelineFor:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"ScreenName"] sinceID:0 startingAtPage:0 count:3];
```

i am getting the response as above;

```
203E8439-3531-4E57-8E47-266EA4DE4F61   //Success String
Data Length= 54804                     //Length of data recieved from connection
Failed Error Description =Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 4.)"       //NSXml Parser Error
```

The problem is with the NSXmlParserError.
If anybody is having any solution to this please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for kind of your information Twitter has Made changes in API. And i think all API responses will be JSON. so better you check it out first.

for your reference: https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine

hope this will help you.